# PDF of product of power law distributed variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider $X_1 \sim f_1 = ax^{a-1}$, $X_2 \sim f_2 = bx^{b-1}$, both independent and defined over the positive domain.
I am interested in the PDF of the product $Z = X_1X_2$.

The know expression of the product distribution is

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_1(x)f_2(z/x)\frac{1}{|x|} dx\\
=\int_{0}^{1}ax^{a-1} b(z/x)^{b-1}\frac{1}{|x|} dx\\
=ab z^{b-1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-b-1} dx\\
\propto z^{b-1}
$$

What I am worried about is the asymmetry: clearly $f_Z(z)$ cannot depend on $b$ alone.

More specifically, because of commutativity of product one can also compute the distribution of $X_2X_1$ to be $\propto z^{a-1}$ which is a contraddiction.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ independent. Never ignore any of the assumptions. You cannot find, nor describe $X_{1}X_{2}$ without the knowledge of them being independent or not . And if not, then how is $(X_{1},X_{2})$ jointly distributed?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - I forgot to mention, but yes $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Indeed the expression for the product distribution holds only for independed RVs. As a side note, I would actually also be interested in the question where $ (X_1,X_2)\sim C(F_1(x), F_2(x))$ for some arbitrary copula $C$, but that's another question :)

Comment: Like I said, for arbirary joint distribution you CANNOT find general results like that. You have to know explicitly what the joint distribution is to say anything at all.

Comment: When people say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$ they mean that you integrate over the region where $f(x)$ is non-zero. For example, $f_{1},f_{2}=0$ for $x\notin(0,1)$ . So modify the limit for integration appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do it is by considering the joint pdf $f(x_{1},x_{2})=abx_{1}^{a-1}x_{2}^{b-1}\,,0<x_{1}<1,0<x_{2}<1$

Now consider $U=X_{1}X_{2}$ and $V=X_{1}$ such that the Jacobian, $|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x_{1},x_{2})}|=x_{1}$

Then the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is given by:-

$$f(u,v)=ab\cdot v^{a-b-1}u^{b-1}\,\,, 0<\frac{u}{v}<1\,,0<v<1 ,$$

Now you integrate over $v$ to find the marginal of $U$ , that is the distribution of $X_{1}X_{2}$

So $$f(u)=\int_{u}^{1}abv^{a-b-1}u^{b-1}\,dv$$

which is just $\displaystyle\frac{ab(u^{a-1}-u^{b-1})}{b-a}\,,0<u<1$

So $U=X_{1}X_{2}$ has density $f(u)=\displaystyle\frac{ab(u^{a-1}-u^{b-1})}{b-a}\,,0<u<1$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please be more specific on how you write the joint of (U,V)?

Comment: Do you know the Jacobian Transformation procedure for random variables?

Comment: I assume you refer to the relation $f(y)=|dx/dy| f(x)$? But U and V are not independent so I'm missing how you get to $f(u,v)$

Comment: If not, then look it up. A quick google search gives you [this](https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/256f19/lectures/256f19Transformations.pdf) and [this](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/23/23.1). Otherwise, open any book on probability. For example, Sheldon Ross' Probability models.

Comment: @semola Yes. But for two variables. $f(u,v)=|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}|f(x_{1},x_{2}) $ . This is nothing but a consequence of the change of variables formula(jacobian transformation) that you learn in multivariable caclulus. So independence has no role to play here. It's just a matter of changing variables for integration. I know it can be confusing at an introductory level, but gradually, you'll develop the intuition for it. And then finally, when you study measure theory, all of these will suddenly make total sense.

Comment: Ok thanks! That's clear now. However, what is formally wrong with the steps I take above?

Comment: As I said, you have to figure out the proper limits of integration. For example, when $z=\frac{1}{2}$ , does it make sense  to integrate over $(0,\frac{1}{2})$? Ofcourse not, because $f_{2}(z/x)=0$ on that region. In any case, more than the asymmetry, what should worry you is that whether what you get is a bonafide pdf or not. That is , is $\int f(z)=1$?

Comment: Of course, clear. Many thanks!

Comment: Also, note that the "formula" for product pdf which you have stated, is precisely what I haved proved by the Jacobian Transformaiton. So, it's wise to remember the principles rather than the formulas.

Comment: I agree with following from first principles, but I'm not sure I see the link to  that formula in your work: I can reach that by considering $P(X_1X_2\le z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_1(x_1)\int_{-\infty}^{z/x_1} f_2(x_2)dx_1dx_2$ (+ same for $X_1\le 0$ ) and taking a derivative to get the PDF

Comment: Oh I guess the same follows from the jacobian transformation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this made me realise it can also be done as below!

Answer (score 1):

### An alternative approach

If $Z=X_1X_2$, then

$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z\le z) = P(X_1X_2\le z)=P(X_2\le z/X_1)\\
=\int_0^1f_1(x_1)\int_0^{z/x_1}f_2(x_2)dx_2dx_1\\
=\int_0^1f_1(x_1)\left(\int_0^{z/x_1}f_2(x_2)dx_2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{z\le x_1}+\int_0^{1}f_2(x_2)dx_2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{z>x_1}\right)dx_1\\
=\int_0^1f_1(x_1)\left(\int_0^{z/x_1}bx_2^{b-1}dx_2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{z\le x_1}+\int_0^{1}bx_2^{b-1}dx_2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{z>x_1}\right)dx_1\\
=\int_0^1f_1(x_1)\left(x_2^b\Bigr|_0^{z/x_1} \cdot\mathbf{1}_{z\le x_1}+x_2^b\Bigr|_0^{1}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{z>x_1}\right)dx_1\\
=\int_0^1f_1(x_1)\left(\frac{z^b}{x_1^b}\mathbf{1}_{z\le x_1}+\mathbf{1}_{z>x_1}\right)dx_1
\\
=\int_z^1f_1(x_1)\frac{z^b}{x_1^b}dx_1+\int_0^zf_1(x_1)dx_1\\
=\int_z^1ax_1^{a-1}\frac{z^b}{x_1^b}dx_1+\int_0^zax_1^{a-1}dx_1\\
=a z^b\int_z^1 x_1^{a-b-1}dx_1+x_1^{a}\Bigr|_0^z\\
=\frac{a z^b}{a-b}x_1^{a-b}\Bigr|_z^1+z^a = \frac{a z^b}{a-b}(1-z^{a-b})+z^a\\
=\frac{az^b-bz^a}{a-b}
$$

Now,
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{d F_Z}{dz} = \frac{ab}{a-b}(z^{b-1}-z^{a-1})$$

Comment: Well done. Solving problems in more than one way is always encouraged. (+1)

Comment: Just one nitpicky unnecessary comment though. Usually, the indicator of a set is denoted by $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ and not delta in probability (as delta stands for Dirac measures) . Else, $\chi$ is also used sometimes in real analysis context. For this answer, it is totally fine. But I would suggest you stick to $\mathbf{1}$ instead of $\delta$ as that is the standard notation.

Comment: Fair enough, amended!